# Invariant subspaces and dimentions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariance

Let V is a finite dimensional vector space over C and T be a linear operator on V . How to prove T has an invariant subspace of dimension k for each k = 1,2, . . . ,dimV .

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by Jordan form. I just give a hint.

Let $\{e_i\}$ is a basis of $V$. Put $J=\lambda I+N$, where $I$ is the identity map, and $N$ is the nilpotent linear map such that sent $e_i$ to $e_{i+1}$(if $i+1>\dim V$, then 0). Every subspace of the form $<a_{k+1}e_{k+1}+,...,+a_ne_n>$ is an invariant subspace of $\dim n-k$.

Comment: How to take $N$  $e_i$ to $e_i+1$

Comment: Can you pls elaborate ??

Comment: Maybe you can try to write the matrix of the linear map $\lambda I+N$ under the basis $<e_i>$. It will show that the matrix is standard Jordon matrix.

Comment: Won't it give only $\lambda$ 's since $N$ is nilpotent then its dimension would be the dimension of $I$

Comment: How to do it  ??